# r - how to add label in corner of polar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a small question: how to add a label in a corner of a polar plot with ggplot?

A reproducible example with some fake data:

```
lab <- data.frame(lab="text")
df2 <- data.frame(x=1:24)
pl <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=1))+geom_point()+
  geom_text(data=lab, x=Inf, y=-Inf, hjust=1, vjust=0, aes(label=lab))
```

This gives me a label in the bottomright corner of the plot. When I transform to polar plot, the label is gone:

```
pl+coord_polar()
```

How to add a label to the bottomright corner in a polar plot?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to annotate using a geom in the coordinates of the data then don't put the label at infinity, but do calculate the position on basis of the eventual polar coordinates:

```
lab <- data.frame(lab="text")
 df2 <- data.frame(x=1:24)
 pl <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=1))+geom_point()+
   geom_text(data=lab, x=10, y=2, hjust=1, vjust=0, aes(label=lab))

 pl+coord_polar()
```

Comment: Thank you! This works with my data, but is there a way to put text in the bottomright corner if the coordinates differ (e.g. when using different facets), using geom_text or otherwise?

Comment: I don't know. I thought that the coordinate system was shared by all layers.